# Search in All Open Documents includes other files at times

Tags: visual-studio-2017, findinfiles

I wonder if others have experienced this and what they have done to fix it.

My project is in VS 2017. Sometimes, after working for a while (searching for some code; change some code; repeat;) when I do a Find in Files for just the open documents, the results returned include results from additional files. It is almost as if the whole project was included in the search.

If I close VS and open the Project again, then the Find in Files for just the open documents behaves as expected. However, after working for a while, I'll notice the unexpected behavior returning.

I have also noticed that if I have extra results, and I open one of the files by clicking on a result for that file, and then close that file, then that file does not appear in search results when I resubmit the search. If I do that for all the extra results, then I finally have the results that I want - for the open files. Note: when I've tested this, I made sure that I only had the files open that I wanted results in. It sounds like this behavior could be for extra open files, but I made sure that there were no extra files.

I have asked my friend Google about this and not found anything. (maybe I'm using the wrong search terms) Thanks for looking at this and for any insight.

Comment: I can confirm every single bit of this question.